# Python win32com deletes text field in Excel

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I read, change and write an Excel file using Python and win32com.

The worksheet contains a text area with some information.

After read, change some cells and write the text area is deleted. The writing is not in any cell near the text area.

What is wrong here?

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb    = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)    
ws    = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
... 
ws.cell(row,col).value = someValue
...
wb.save(filename=filename)
```

Comment: May not be important but I think it should be `ws.Cells()`, and the `Save()` method does not take any parameters.

Comment: Argh ... copied this from two different sections in my code. The second is from openpyxl, while the first one is from win32com. So openpyxl deletes the text area amd not win32com. Thank you for the "hint".

Comment: Yes, win32com and openpyxl work in two different ways as you know. `win32com` actually drives the Excel application (in essence like a VBA macro), while `openpyxl` just works on the file itself, as it knows the xml structure of a `.xlsx` file. I would hesitate to mix the two in an application unless you are very strict about which has control of a file at any given time: you run the risk of openpyxl modifying something in a file and win32com/Excel being unaware of the change. If it is just data in/data out to a file, I'd stick with openpyxl (especially if using pandas).